How to install a specific version of postgresql in ubuntu?
I need to install postgresql 14.12. I've setup the repository like in the manual section:
But I did not find postgresql 14.12, only 14.13.


Well, obviously, the package you want is not in the repository, so you'll have to find another way to install it.
